# Best optimization for PGSQL Similarity

Tags: php, postgresql

I am beginner php developer. I need use in my project function similarity from pgsql.

I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name
    (id serial primary key, 
     prg_id TEXT,  
     code TEXT,  
     city TEXT,  
     area TEXT, 
     street TEXT, 
     numer TEXT,, 
     address TEXT)
```

This is very big table.

Now i need search in this table.

I have SQL ex:

```
SELECT street,  
     similarity('street'  , 'name street') AS similarity,  
     row_number() OVER () AS rank  
     FROM   table_name  
     where street% 'name street'  
     order by rank LIMIT  1;
```

It's work, but slow.

Is it possible to write this question better to make it more efficient?

Comment: what's wrong with my question? Why minus?

Comment: How is this `php` related?

Comment: @brombeer : His question is related to postgresql. He wants his query to run faster

Comment: @Philippe I can see that. The question has been tagged with `php` though. No `php` code to be seen anywhere

Comment: Your query as it doesn't make sense.  You are taking the lowest ranked row, but you are not ranking *by* anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rewrite the query slightly and create a GiST index, it can be fast:

```
CREATE INDEX ON table_name USING gist (street gist_trgm_ops);
```

Then you have to use the distance operator `<->` instead of the `similarity` function:

```
SELECT street,  
       street <-> 'name street' AS distance
       row_number() OVER () AS rank
FROM table_name  
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1;
```

That will give you the row where `street` is most similar to `'name street'`. You can add a `WHERE` condition if you want to exclude results that are not similar enough.

Answer (score 0):

Install the extension [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html), create an index on this column:

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON table_name USING GIST (street gist_trgm_ops);
```

And use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) for your SQL statement to get the query plan. Did it improve or not?